# In a non static class ,How do I retain the value of a static variable used in a static method called in multiple different classes simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, methods, static

I have a non static class with a static method in it and a static variable of type **ChangeCkecker**

**This code (ChangeChecker). 'Changed' takes in a object parameter , checks it against another object return true if the two do not match**

```
        public class ChangeChecker
    {

        public object Backup_Object_Value;

        public ChangeChecker() { }
        public bool Changed(object obj)
        {
            bool result = false;

            if (!obj.Equals(Backup_Object_Value))
            {
                Backup_Object_Value = obj;
                result = true;
            }
            return result;

        }

    }
```

**in my static method in my non-static class 'ClassA' I want to carry out a function only when 'Changed' is true**

```
        public class ClassA
    {
        private static ChangeChecker value = new ChangeChecker();

        public static void MethodA(Rect area)
        {
            if(value.Changed(area))
            {
                Debug.Log("ChangeMade");
            }

        }

    }
```

**ClassB and ClassC both call classA.MethodA**

```
    public class ClassB
    {

        void Update()
        {
            ClassA.MethodA(new Rect(2,2,20,20));
        }
    }
    public class ClassC
    {

        void Update()
        {
            ClassA.MethodA(new Rect(0,100,100,100));
        }
    }
```

What is happening is that because ClassB and ClassC are both calling ClassA.MethodA simultaneously, ClassA ChangeChecker variable gets overridden and the function stops working correctly

Is there a attribute that I can use to mark up the ChangeChecker variable in ClassA so that it is not overridden each time ?

This works perfectly outside of use in static classes and static methods because I would be working with instances of ChangeChecker . Can you help me to get this working correctly ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: When you say "simultaneously", does that mean multiple threads?

Comment: You are aware that the `Backup_Object_Value` you store is a reference to the passed in `obj` right? That means that even if `obj` has a property change, the equality will still succeed and it will show as it not being changed. The only way the equality will fail is if the passed in object now points to a `new` object, otherwise both are the same.

Comment: The code actually will continuously detect inequality and print out 'ChangeMade'.  Both `ClassB` and `ClassC` are passing a value into  ClassA.MethodA

if only `ClassB` or `ClassA` was passing a value into  `ClassA.MethodA` then there would `ClassA` `Changed` would return true only when `obj` is not equal to `Backup_Object_Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming that `ClassB` and `ClassC` will run on different threads:**

Using `lock` or the `ThreadStatic` attribute will produce two different behaviors. They are not two options to solve the same problem.

If you use `lock` (without `ThreadStatic`), the two threads will share the same `Backup_Object_Value` object.

Consider this Example:

1) Thread 1 changed value to VALUE1 -> system says value was changed

2) Thread 2 changed value to VALUE2 -> system says value was changed

3) Thread 1 changed value to VALUE1 -> system says value was changed

If you use `ThreadStatic`, the two threads will have their own instances of `ChangeChecker` and thus `Backup_Object_Value`, and the following happens:

1) Thread 1 changed value to VALUE1 -> system says value was changed

2) Thread 2 changed value to VALUE2 -> system says value was changed

3) Thread 1 changed value to VALUE1 -> system says value was **NOT** changed

Please select which approach you want to use based on the behavior you would like to have.

**Assuming that `ClassB` and `ClassC` will call `ClassA.MethodA` from the same thread, then you have the following options:**

Option #1:

Make `ClassA.MethodA` (and the `ChangeChecker value` field) non-static. And then let `ClassB` and `ClassC` have their own private instances instance of `ClassA`, like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    private ChangeChecker value = new ChangeChecker();

    public void MethodA(Rect area)
    {
        if (value.Changed(area))
        {
            Debug.Log("ChangeMade");
        }
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    private readonly ClassA m_ClassAInstance = new ClassA();

    void Update()
    {
        m_ClassAInstance.MethodA(new Rect(2, 2, 20, 20));
    }
}
public class ClassC
{
    private readonly ClassA m_ClassAInstance = new ClassA();

    void Update()
    {
        m_ClassAInstance.MethodA(new Rect(0, 100, 100, 100));
    }
}
```

Please note that that I am not using Dependency Injection here. This works, but you might want to change this to inject instances of ClassA into ClassB and ClassC.

Option #2:

**Note: the first option is the better one. Use this second approach only as a last resort. I wouldn't consider this option a good design.**

Add a parameter to `ClassA.MethodA` to identify the calling object, and then create a list to hold different values of `ChangeChecker` for each object, like this:

```
public class ObjectAndChangeChecker
{
    public WeakReference ObjectReference { get; set; }
    public ChangeChecker ChangeChecker { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA
{
    private static List<ObjectAndChangeChecker> m_ObjectAndChangeCheckers = new List<ObjectAndChangeChecker>();

    private static ChangeChecker GetOrAddChangeChecker(object calling_object)
    {
        //Get rid of ObjectAndChangeChecker objects than contain garbage collected objects
        m_ObjectAndChangeCheckers = m_ObjectAndChangeCheckers.Where(x => x.ObjectReference.IsAlive).ToList();

        var object_and_change_checker =
            m_ObjectAndChangeCheckers.FirstOrDefault(
                x => object.ReferenceEquals(calling_object, x.ObjectReference.Target));

        if (object_and_change_checker == null)
        {
            object_and_change_checker = new ObjectAndChangeChecker()
            {
                ChangeChecker = new ChangeChecker(),
                ObjectReference = new WeakReference(calling_object)
            };

            m_ObjectAndChangeCheckers.Add(object_and_change_checker);

        }

        return object_and_change_checker.ChangeChecker;
    }

    public static void MethodA(Rect area, object calling_object)
    {
        var value = GetOrAddChangeChecker(calling_object);

        if (value.Changed(area))
        {
            Debug.Log("ChangeMade");
        }

    }
}
```

Change `ClassB` and `ClassC` to pass `this` to `MethodA`

```
public class ClassB
{

    public void Update()
    {
        ClassA.MethodA(new Rect(2, 2, 20, 20), this);
    }
}
public class ClassC
{

    public void Update()
    {
        ClassA.MethodA(new Rect(0, 100, 100, 100), this);
    }
}
```

Please note that in this case, each instance of ClassB or ClassC will have its own `ChangeChecker`. If you want to share the same `ChangeChecker` for all instances of ClassB for example, then pass `this.GetType()` instead of `this`. Like this:

```
public class ClassB
{

    public void Update()
    {
        ClassA.MethodA(new Rect(2, 2, 20, 20), this.GetType());
    }
}
```

Important note: Please make sure that `Rect.Equals` actually works as expected.

Comment: exactly as you said " 
The two threads will share the same Backup_Object_Value object. Which means that if thread 1 set the value to VALUE1, then thread 2 set the value to VALUE2, then thread 1 set the value again to VALUE1, the system will think that the value has changed"

Comment: Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: what is strange is that the system thinks that the value is still constantly changing  even though I have marked up ChangeChecker value with [ThreadStatic]

`   [ThreadStatic]
            private static ChangeChecker GridAreaChangeCheck = new ChangeChecker();`

Comment: Are you sure that class B and class C always run on different threads?

Comment: @DMDev, is Equals defined on your Rect class/struct correctly?

Comment: ahh Rect is part of the UnityEngine library.
I am reading [threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) so to get a much better understanding of threading.

From my reading so far it seems at though ClassB and ClassC are both run on the main thread.

Comment: @DMDev, If ClassB and ClassC run on the same thread, then this is totally a different question.

Comment: In that case , what can I do ?

Comment: Is it an option to make `MethodA` (and `ChangeChecker value`) non-static, and then have private instances of `ClassA` inside `ClassB` and `ClassC`?

Comment: Sure , However the code becomes more complex. Since I will be working with different instances of Class A wherever i need to use MethodA. It is a last resort if what i'm asking for is not yet possible.

Comment: Is it an option, to add another parameter to the `ClassA.MethodA` method? A parameter that identifies the caller. It could be a `Guid` generated by the calling class. Or It could be the calling object itself (as `object`). You could then create a dictionary to hold multiple instances of `Backup_Object_Value`. This dictionary will contain a different backup object for each key (caller).

Comment: I understand what you are saying and it seems to make sense but I don't know how to implement it . Could you give me an example?

Comment: Thanks a lot , I'm going to go with option 1 , after reading through Option 2 i realised that there were some stuff that i am not used to and  it wouldn't be wise for me to use it without understanding it .

Later on , if I find a way to keep my  method static and still maintain a unique `Backup_Object_Value` then i will revert

Answer (score 2):

> What is happening is that because ClassB and ClassC are both calling ClassA.MethodA simultaneously, ClassA ChangeChecker variable gets overridden and the function stops working correctly

This will only be true if multiple threads are accessing the static method.

If that is not the case, the first call to the static method will complete before the second one begins.

If you are accessing it from multiple threads, you need to include appropriate multithreaded safety.  You can start by examining the [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement.

If you need more information on multi-threaded programming, this is my [favorite tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to the tutorial. I will read through it fully before giving any more replies to answers because I do not understand threading yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark the fields with the value [`ThreadStatic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute which will give each thread it's own instance of the variable to play with rather than sharing it with the other thread.

As an alternative solution, I would recommend using [`lock`:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

```
    public bool Changed(object obj)
    {
        bool result = false;

        lock(Backup_Object_Value)
        {
           if (obj.Equals(Backup_Object_Value)) { }
           else
           {
              Backup_Object_Value = obj;
              result = true;
           }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Which will ensure that multiple threads do not intervene with the same object.

Comment: If you are marking the `static ChangeChecker value` field with `ThreadStatic`, then you don't need to use the `lock` since each thread will have its own copy of `ChangeChecker`

Comment: @YacoubMassad - yes I was just pointing out another alternative solution.

Comment: If you use `lock` without using `ThreadStatic` you will have a totally different behavior than using `ThreadStatic` without `lock`.

Comment: In the first case, the two threads will share the same Backup_Object_Value object. Which means that if thread 1 set the value to VALUE1, then thread 2 set the value to VALUE2, then thread 1 set the value again to VALUE1, the system will think that the value has changed.

Comment: However, with the second case, having the same set of events will make the system know that the value was not changed.

Comment: @Darren: ThreadStatic effectively treats the property as an instance property, unless each thread has multiple instances of the object (I know that's not technically how it works, but logically paints the picture).  That may not be the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this , I haven't gotten the code to work yet . I wam reading up on [threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) so to understand things better

Answer (score 1):

Well you can....

Read on sharing resources in multithreaded applications (hint: use the [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) construct).

or

Mark your static field `value` with [`ThreadStatic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static ChangeChecker value = new ChangeChecker();
```

Which means each thread that accesses it will have its own copy of the field. But if that's the case, maybe you don't need those members to be static at all. But I don't know all your constraints so it's up to you to decide.

Also you could make your code slightly more readable with

```
if (!obj.Equals(Backup_Object_Value)) {
    Backup_Object_Value = obj;
    return true;
}

return false;
```

instead of the empty `if`. Also you can get rid of your local `bool` variable.

Comment: Thank you for point this out  if (!obj.Equals(Backup_Object_Value))

Sure thing , I will use [ThreadStatic]

Comment: ThreadStatic gives each thread it's own "copy" of the static variable.  At that point you may as well have an instance variable, unless each thread has multiple instances of your object.  Be sure you fully understand what this does.

Comment: @EricJ. Was that for me? Because that's already covered in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the overriding of last changed object value being updated simultaneously; you can enhance your checker class to keep record of the all changes done.

For multithreaded environment you can use the  [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331(v=vs.110).aspx). I have tweaked your `Checker` to kee all the changes which are being made.

- with `Changed` method new value will be compared to the last change.
- `HasChanges` property can give if there are any previous changes.
- `AcceptChanges` will return all the changes and clear out the history of changes done.
- And it's threadsafe.

  ```
  public class ChangeChecker
   {
      private object Backup_Object_Value;
      private readonly object synchronizationToken = new object();
      private readonly ConcurrentStack<object> changes = new ConcurrentStack<object>();

      public bool HasChanges
      {
          get
          {
              return changes.Count > 0;
          }
      }

      public ChangeChecker() { }

      public bool Changed(object obj)
      {
          bool result = false;
          lock (synchronizationToken)
          {
            if (changes.TryPeek(out Backup_Object_Value) && !obj.Equals(Backup_Object_Value))
              {
                changes.Push(obj);
                result = true;
               }
           }

          return result;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Returns all changes and clearout the history.
      /// </summary>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public IEnumerable<object> AcceptChanges()
      {
        lock (synchronizationToken)
         {
            // keep the last updated of the object, if exists
            if (!changes.TryPeek(out Backup_Object_Value))
            {
                yield break;
            }
          }

          while (changes.Count > 0)
          {
              object obj;
              if (changes.TryPop(out obj))
              {
                 yield return obj;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This should give you a better way for change tracking of an object in multithreaded environment. Also there are always chances to improvement so change it as you may.